# In the figure below, blacken $3$ of them such that $3$ colored boxes will form a straight line. How many different methods are there?

Tags: combinatorics

In the figure below, blacken $3$ of them such that $3$ colored boxes will form a straight line. How many different methods are there?

[image]

I tried to count them all manually and I got 50 as my answer. I am trying to find a way to solve it using combinatorics.

Comment: Do they need to be consecutive?

Comment: Do the bottom three count as “on a straight line?”

Comment: @greenturtle3141 based on what I did, I make sure that they are connected or consecutive.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Based on what I did, the bottom is not counted

Comment: I also got $50$, assuming the rules that you stated. I just counted it manually, but you can systematically count it by first splitting into 3 cases depending on the direction of the line. Then you simply just need to go through every hexagon and assume that it is a middle piece of the black line. Check if there exists another $2$ hexagons on either side of it. Count it if there is.